# Unable to use the value from choicePrompt in Chatbot V4 Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AdaptiveCards;
using CoreBot;
using CoreBot.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Dialogs
{
    public class SharepointDialog : CancelAndHelpDialog
    {
        private const string DestinationStepMsgText = "Enter the type of document you want to search ";
        private const string OriginStepMsgText = "Enter the name of document you want to search";
        string documentName = null;
        string documentType = null;
        public string CHOICEPROMPT { get; private set; }
        public object AdaptiveCard { get; private set; }

        public SharepointDialog()
            : base(nameof(SharepointDialog))
        {
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
            AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new DateResolverDialog());
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                DestinationStepAsync,
                OriginStepAsync,
                ConfirmStepAsync,
                FinalStepAsync,
            }));



            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }

        //private static async Task SendIntroCardAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        //{
        //    var card = new HeroCard();
        //    card.Title = "Welcome to Bot Framework!";
        //    card.Text = @"Welcome to Welcome Users bot sample! This Introduction card
        //                 is a great way to introduce your Bot to the user and suggest
        //                 some things to get them started. We use this opportunity to
        //                 recommend a few next steps for learning more creating and deploying bots.";
        //    card.Images = new List<CardImage>() { new CardImage("https://aka.ms/bf-welcome-card-image") };
        //    card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
        //    {
        //        new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "HR Contingent", null, "HR Contingency", "Get an overview", "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0"),
        //        new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Management Tools", null, "Management Tools", "Ask a question", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework"),
        //    };

        //    var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
        //    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
        //}
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DestinationStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var docNameDetails = (SharepointDetails)stepContext.Options;
            //docNameDetails.DocType = (string)stepContext.Result;

            if (docNameDetails.DocType == null)
            {
                var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(DestinationStepMsgText, DestinationStepMsgText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);

                   var choices = new[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync("ShowChoicePrompt", new PromptOptions
            {
                Style = ListStyle.SuggestedAction,
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please select from choices"),
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, Please the valid choice"),
                Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(choices),
            }, cancellationToken);
                // return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.NextAsync(docNameDetails.DocType, cancellationToken);
        }

        private static async Task SendResCardAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, List<string> resSpList)

        {
            var card = new HeroCard();
            card.Title = "Sharepoint Result";
            card.Text = @"Click on below result";
            card.Images = new List<CardImage>() { new CardImage("https://aka.ms/bf-welcome-card-image") };

            foreach (var rs in resSpList)
            {

                string[] subLink = rs.Split('/');
                string docTitle = subLink[subLink.Length - 1];
                card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, docTitle, null, docTitle, "All",rs),


            };
            }
            var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> OriginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var docNameDetails = (SharepointDetails)stepContext.Options;

            docNameDetails.DocType = (string)stepContext.Result;

            if (docNameDetails.SharepointSearch == null)
            {
                var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(OriginStepMsgText, OriginStepMsgText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
            }


            return await stepContext.NextAsync(docNameDetails.SharepointSearch, cancellationToken);
        }



        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ConfirmStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var docNameDetails = (SharepointDetails)stepContext.Options;
            docNameDetails.SharepointSearch= (string)stepContext.Result;

            var messageText = $"Please confirm docName: {docNameDetails.SharepointSearch}  and docType: {docNameDetails.DocType}  Is this correct?";
            var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
            documentName = docNameDetails.SharepointSearch;
            documentType = docNameDetails.DocType;
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();
            SharepointSearchDialog sharepointservice = new SharepointSearchDialog();
            res = await sharepointservice.SharepointSearchEng(documentName, documentType);
            SendResCardAsync(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken, res);
            if ((bool)stepContext.Result)
            {
                var bookingDetails = (BookingDetails)stepContext.Options;

                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(bookingDetails, cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }

        private static bool IsAmbiguous(string timex)
        {
            var timexProperty = new TimexProperty(timex);
            return !timexProperty.Types.Contains(Constants.TimexTypes.Definite);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to display choice menu using suggestion card and then select docType But after selecting the file type i.e One then code fails with unknown error..
ChoicePrompt doesn't work in section  ,if (docNameDetails.DocType == null).
Instead of One Two and Three i will use document type such as pdf,xls,docx etc .
Code fails with null reference exception .Please Help.

Note: TextPrompt works but choicePrompt doesn't work.

In function OriginStepAsync :
docNameDetails.docType throws null pointer reference.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Faced something similar for msTeams channel. I changed the style property of PromptOptions to ListStyle.HeroCard.

Problem I have noticed is, there is a slight difference in behavior of choice prompts for different channels. Playing around with different values for PromptOptions properties helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am still getting same error: bot encountered an error. I don't think style would matter here. I checked with various available styles and also removed the style property and checked .Still same error.

Comment: Is there any exception you are getting? Stack trace of same will be helpful in understanding the issue better.